# Update two column from different table in single query in sql server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 3 tables

```
Table1

     Sno   sname amount
       1     aaa   23
       2      bbb  34
      3      ccc   98

Table2

     sno   sprice
      1      34
      2      78
      3      87

Table3

     sno    amount    sprice
      1      65        78
      2      43        76
      3      34        45
```

i want to write single update query to update table1 and table2 table compare with table3

sno column.

**Result is**

Table1

```
Sno   sname amount
   1     aaa   65
   2      bbb  43
  3      ccc   34

The Amount column value table3 is updated into table1 amount column.
```

Table2

```
 sno   sprice
  1      78
  2      76
  3      48
```

The sprice value of table3 is updated into table2 sprice column.

This two operation can do in single update query itself.

If it is possible please help me.

Answer (score 0):

An UPDATE statement can only ever affect a single table (aside from separate statements such as those that might be contained in a trigger). Why not just wrap the two update statements in a transaction? What is the goal of trying to do this in a single statement?

Answer (score 0):

You can cascade updates to a single table (see code example) using primary and foreign keys; unfortunately you can't do this with more than one table from each source table unless the foreign keys for the two target tables are the same (it's also a little ugly in terms of primary key on the source table!!).

You could also use triggers here (carefully!).

Here's the code for a cascade from table3 to table1 anyway:

```
-- Set up Data
CREATE TABLE table1 (
    sno SMALLINT,
    sname VARCHAR(3),
    amount INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_table1 PRIMARY KEY (
        sno,
        amount
    )
)

INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (1, 'aaa', 23)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (2, 'bbb', 34)
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES (3, 'ccc', 98)

CREATE TABLE table2 (
    sno SMALLINT,
    sprice INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_table2 PRIMARY KEY (
        sno,
        sprice
    )
)

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (1, 34)
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (2, 78)
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES (3, 87)


CREATE TABLE table3 (
    sno SMALLINT,
    amount INT,
    sprice INT,
    CONSTRAINT PK_table3 PRIMARY KEY (
        sno,
        amount
    )
)

-- Data same as table1 and table2 for starting
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (1, 23, 34)
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (2, 34, 78)
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES (3, 98, 87)

-- Cascading updates between foreign keyed tables
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD CONSTRAINT FK_table1_table3 FOREIGN KEY (sno, amount) REFERENCES table3 (sno, amount) ON UPDATE CASCADE

-- Original Table 1
SELECT * FROM table1

-- Updates table 3 (cascades to table 1)
UPDATE table3
SET amount = 65,
    sprice = 78
WHERE sno = 1

UPDATE table3
SET amount = 43,
    sprice = 76
WHERE sno = 2

UPDATE table3
SET amount = 34,
    sprice = 45
WHERE sno = 3

-- Prove cascade
SELECT *
FROM table1

--Tidy Up
DROP TABLE table1
DROP TABLE table2
DROP TABLE table3
```